# cisco 515 pat and port redirection to dmz and inside interfaces

Tags: cisco

I have an cisco pix 515e running ver 7.0(6). I have one static public IP that my ISP gives me and I am using pat to the inside and dmz interfaces. I need to redirect some ports to forward to the DMZ, and some to forward to the inside interface. How can I have two static statements binding the the pat outside to the inside and the dmz?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco calls this "Static PAT."  Something like this:

```
static (inside,outside) tcp interface http inside_host_ip_address http netmask 255.255.255.255
```

See [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa70/command/reference/s.html#wp1540284) for more info.